# ¿Como añadir espacios en blanco en una cadena de texto en C#?

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente variable la cual quiero agregarle espacios en blanco

```
string Numero; // el valor que contiene es 147812357898
```

y quiero agregarle espacios de modo que quede asi:

```
"1478 12355 7898"
```

Comment: Haz desde el inicio `string Numero = "1478 12355 7898";`. Si no puedes hacer eso, me temo que tu pregunta está incompleta. Por favor lee [ask].

Comment: lo siento ya lo edite no me habia dado a entender correctamente.

Comment: ¿hay algún patrón con el que sabes dónde van a ir los espacios? ¿o siempre van en la misma posición?

Answer (score 2):

Podrias evaluar usar `Regular Expression`

[Sustituciones en expresiones regulares](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions)

quizas algo como esto

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var input = "147812357898";
        var reg = @"\d{4}";
        string result = Regex.Replace(input, reg, " $0");

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No puedes modificar cadenas ya que son inmutables. Pero puedes hacer esto:

```
string nuevoNumero = Numero.Substring(0,3) + " " + Numero.Substring(4,8) + " " + Numero.Substring(9,12);
```

Ten en cuenta que si la longitud de la cadena "Numero" varía, podrías utilizar un índice "i" para acceder a cada parte de dicha cadena.